# How to count the ocurrence of each diferent matches of the same regex

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, grep

I have a text file that and I want to count the ocurrence of each matches of a regex using grep

I have a text file like:

```
# file.txt

72=JABBA123
72=JABBA123
72=THE5555
72=THE5555
72=THE5555
72=HUTT66
```

I want to count using grep like:

```
grep -c -Op "72=(\w+\d+)" file.txt
```

Than the result should be like:

```
JABBA123 2
THE5555  3
HUTT66   1
```

Comment: What's `-O` and `-p`?

Comment: `awk -F'=' '{count[$2]++} END {for (word in count) print word, count[word]}' file`

Comment: I use it to return the matching group like
grep -Op "72=(\K\w+\d+)" file.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -Po "[[:alpha:]]+[[:digit:]]+" file | uniq -c
```

or

```
grep -Po '=\K.*' file | uniq -c
```

> `\K`: removes matching part before `\K`

Output:

```
      2 JABBA123
      3 THE5555
      1 HUTT66
```

Possibly a `sort` has to be inserted here.